# Keyboard Module in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, keyboard-events, pypi, keyboard-hook

I was looking for a module that can do for me keyboard hooks in order to create abbreviations and actions that I will choose.

The best result I have found appear to be this module:
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/keyboard

Unfortantely, the hooks don't work for me. Functions like add_abbreviation and add_hotkey don't work.

I'm running python 2.7 Anaconda, on windows 8.

I tried also to run as administrator, but it doesn't work.

I will appreciate any kind of help :)

EDIT: The code that I'm trying to execute:

```
import keyboard
keyboard.add_abbreviation('@@', 'some other text')
keyboard.wait()
```

Comment: Can you provide any can sample?

Comment: @LaurentLAPORTE edited

Comment: Try to replace the `@@` abbrevation with something else, e.g. `1`. Then type `1` followed by space to see if expanding the apprevation works. Special characters like `@` can cause problems when using different keyboard layouts. I'm using the German keyboard layout and the `@` doesn't work, but most other keys do.

Answer (score 1):

Even I can't get this working on linux.

```
import keyboard
keyboard.add_abbreviation('@@', 'some other text')
keyboard.wait()
```

However, following works for me:-

```
import keyboard
keyboard.add_abbreviation('b', 'some other text')
```

There seems to be some issue with symbols.

Answer (score -1):

When using Python 2.7 on Windows 10, the following code works like a charm:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import keyboard
keyboard.add_hotkey('a', lambda: print('A key pressed'))
keyboard.wait()
```

I'd also recommend the [github project](https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard/) of keyboard which contains examples and documentation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the following code not working for me. I read almost all of the documentation...